# angular ui-router nested views can't display?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I try modify my project to user angular ui-router, but it can't work,the views can't display,who can help me,thanks. The flowing is my file:

```
app.js, index.html, home.html, leftTree.html, topBar.html, ihome.html, footer.html
```

```js
angular.module('agentApp', ['ngCookies', 'ui.router', 'agentApp.controllers', 'agentApp.directives', 'agentapp.filters', 'agentApp.services'])

.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

  $stateProvider
    .state('index', {      
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'tpls/home.html'
    })
    .state('index.home', {
      url:'/home',
      views: {
        "leftTree": {
          templateUrl: "tpls/leftTree.html"
        },
        "topBar": {
          templateUrl: "tpls/topBar.html"
        },
        "ihome": {
          template: "tpls/ihome.html"
        },
        "footer": {
          templateUrl: "tpls/footer.html"
        }
      }
    })
}])
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="agentApp" ng-controller="validUserCtrl">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title ng-bind="title">Document</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Morris -->
<link href="css/plugins/morris/morris-0.4.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Gritter
    <link href="js/plugins/gritter/jquery.gritter.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->
<!-- Toastr style -->
<link href="css/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="homeCtrl" ng-cloak>
 <div ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

home.html

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-collapse">
      <div ui-view="leftTree"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">
    <div class="row border-bottom">
      <div ui-view="topBar"></div>
  
    </div>
  
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content" ng-cloak>
  
      <div ui-view="ihome"></div>
  
      <div class="footer">
        <div ui-view="footer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

leftTree.html

```html
<div class="siderbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
        <li>demo menu 1</li>
        <li>demo menu 2</li>
        <li>demo menu 3</li>
        <li>demo menu 4</li>
        <li>demo menu 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

topBar.html

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top white-bg" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a href="loginManager!logout.action">
                <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>{{ 'Logout' | lan }}
            </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

ihome.html

```html
<div>I am main home page</div>
```

footer.html

```html
<footer>
    <p> copyfight &copy; myapp
  </footer>
```

The attach file is I  want the content display place
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idvsC.png)

Comment: What is the problem in this code?

Comment: The views template no display,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made you jsfiddle with similar route definition.
http://jsfiddle.net/vzmddcdL/

1. Make `index` state an abstract.
2. `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` should point `("/home")`;
3. `index.home` doesn't need `/` in `url` definition because it's a child state of `index` which already defines `/` in `url` ...so `/` + `home` = `/home`

   `.state('index.home', {
         url:'home',
         views: {`

Answer (score 0):

Since the uiViews iHome, footer, topBar and leftTree are actually inside the index.home state, you need to specify the views like this:

```
     views: {
    "leftTree@index.home": {
      templateUrl: "tpls/leftTree.html"
    },
    "topBar@index.home": {
      templateUrl: "tpls/topBar.html"
    },
    "ihome@index.home": {
      template: "tpls/ihome.html"
    },
    "footer@index.home": {
      templateUrl: "tpls/footer.html"
    }
```

Without the "@index.home" part, ui-router tries to look for the named views in the parent state, the index state in index.html that contains the one unnamed view for showing your home state only.